# Check JS variable on page reload and hide/show divs accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page with 4 divs (doctors, diagnosis, surgeries, and medications)

```
<div id="menubar" class="noprint">
    <?php include "structure/menu.php";?>
</div>
<div id="diagnosis">
    <?php include "structure/diagnosis.php";?>
</div>
<div id="doctors">
    <?php include "structure/doctors.php";?>
</div>
<div id="medications">
    <?php include "structure/medications.php";?>
</div>
<div id="surgeries">
    <?php include "structure/surgeries.php";?>
</div>
```

I have a `.js` file that activates when the menu buttons in the menudiv are clicked:

```
function medbutton() {
    $("#diagnosis").hide();
    $("#doctors").hide();
    $("#medications").show();
    $("#surgeries").hide();
    selector = "medical";
    alert(selector);
}
function diagbutton() {
    $("#diagnosis").show();
    $("#doctors").hide();
    $("#medications").hide();
    $("#surgeries").hide();
    selector = "diag";
    alert(selector);
}
function drbutton() {
    $("#diagnosis").hide();
    $("#doctors").show();
    $("#medications").hide();
    $("#surgeries").hide();
    selector = "doctor";
    alert(selector);
}
function surgbutton() {
    $("#diagnosis").hide();
    $("#doctors").hide();
    $("#medications").hide();
    $("#surgeries").show();
    selector = "surgery";
    alert(selector);
}
```

As you can see, I've used `alert(var)` to let me know that `selector` is being changed, and it is (the alert shows the correct var).

What I want to have happen is, when the page reloads (from navigation within the domain on those included `.php` files, have the page `.show()` the div that was last open (this the `selector` `var`).

When I refresh the page, it blanks out all the divs (as it is supposed to on initial load):

var selector;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#diagnosis").hide();
    $("#doctors").hide();
    $("#medications").hide();
    $("#surgeries").hide();
    if (selector == "medical") {
        $("#medications").show();
    }
    if (selector == "doctor") {
        $("#doctors").show();
    }
    if (selector == "diag") {
        $("#diagnosis").show();
    }
    if (selector == "surgery") {
        $("#surgeries").show();
    }

});
```

Any ideas how to get this to work? I've not used cookies before, but I suppose I could learn how to use them and just throw an expiration of like 20 minutes or something, but is there a way close to what I'm using that would theoretically work?

Comment: You could use a cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage, or the url

Comment: k - I'll start learning how to do those, but if anyone has any alternative suggestions, I'd like to expand my knowledge base

Comment: one possibility is to include the var in the url of every link that reloades the page. not a good one, but possible. other (better) to save a cookie when you set the var

Comment: When you change content, you should change url - how do you know what content you must show? Other thing is SEO.

Comment: could cut that code down by about two thirds by using common class on those groups...hide the class...show the ID

Comment: can you fiddle or show me an example here, not 100% what you are saying to do, but any abbreviation of code is good by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selector = getCookie("sel");
    $("#diagnosis").hide();
    $("#doctors").hide();
    $("#medications").hide();
    $("#surgeries").hide();
    if (selector == "medical") {
        $("#medications").show();
    }
    if (selector == "doctor") {
        $("#doctors").show();
    }
    if (selector == "diag") {
        $("#diagnosis").show();
    }
    if (selector == "surgery") {
        $("#surgeries").show();
    }

});
```

The `getCookie()`function is from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
You can set the cookie like:

```
document.cookie="sel=doctor";
```

### [Simple JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5b5ndq9/)

Comment: Looks good - I added this and the setCookies and it works just fine.

Comment: @jpgerb glad I could help :D